# Mercurial corruption? "No such file or directory"

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm currently running Mercurial 6.4.2. I've been using TortoiseHg for a long time and just started running into this recurring issue where if I update some files in specific folders, or if I delete those folders and then try to add them back, I get this error:

[image]

These are binary files. `hg verify` turned up a few issues with the repo, so I concluded that some of the history for these files had become irredeemably corrupted. I then tried a full `hg convert --config convert.hg.ignoreerrors=True sqs sqsfix` as mentioned on the [repository corruption page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryCorruption). I went through each of the 288 corrupted files and removed  the .i files as suggested on that page until the conversion finished. `hg verify` reports no issues for the new converted repo.

Then I copied the most up to date versions of the .dwg files whose history had been corrupted to the converted repo with the hopes that I could just commit those and then resume development from there. Nope, I get the exact same error that I started with:

[image]

I have no idea what to do now or what the issue might be, and Google doesn't turn up anything for this issue.

Comment: In these rare situations I usually get a brand new clone from whatever master or upstream repo you have, and forget about the broken one.  Do you have unpushed commits?

Comment: The issue is in the upstream as well, so fresh clones exhibit the corruption. The issue committing to the clean copy has to do with file paths that are too long. Will post a follow-up answer with details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is [a recently discovered issue](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg/-/issues/5913) with Mercurial itself when the file paths get too long, it messes up the backup files that you see in the error message. This is probably what caused the original corruption, it just proceeded silently prior to Mercurial 6.x series. Starting sometime in the 6.x series it started actively reporting the issue which is when we started seeing these errors.

I've confirmed that Mercurial 6.5 fixes the issue completely.

Comment: Great find - this will be very helpful I'm sure!